# Set local network IP placeholder in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, xdebug

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file where I'm setting `xdebug` settings for the container, such as host, port and remote mode.
While port and remote mode don't change, the host is different for me when I'm at work or at home.
Also at work, we ofc have all a different local network ip address, so we always need to change the host ip manually.
If there's a better way to do this, please tell me, but if not :

How can I add a placeholder inside the `docker-compose.yml` for the local network ip?
 It currently looks like this

```
worker:
    image: docker.io/company/project-dev
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_HOST=192.168.2.198
      - XDEBUG_PORT=9000
      - XDEBUG_REMOTE_MODE=req
```

I would need to somehow set the host like this

`- XDEBUG_HOST={local-ip}`

but what is the best way do achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value to be a variable:

```
worker:
    image: docker.io/company/project-dev
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_HOST=${local_ip}
      - XDEBUG_PORT=9000
      - XDEBUG_REMOTE_MODE=req
```

And then set an environment variable when calling docker-compose up:

```
local_ip=123.123.123.123 docker-compose up
```

Comment: Yes, but then everyone would need to start it like this. I know, I could set up an alias for that, but isn't there a possibility to do that totally magic?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: I'll try that out tomorrow

Comment: You can define the variable in .env https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

Answer (score 0):

Answering really late but for that sort of need, I use [overrides](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) of the main `docker-compose.yml` file.

In your case, you would simply override the `XDEBUG_HOST` in a `docker-compose.override.yml` file:

```
# docker-compose.override.yml
worker:
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_HOST=192.168.2.198
```

With `docker-compose.yml` being versioned, and `docker-compose.override.yml` staying strictly local and not versioned.

That way you still have a functioning configuration in case `docker-compose.override.yml` is missing, and anybody in your team can create that file according to their local environment.